# Why my below code is not creating any Kendo widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

Could someone tell me why the below code is not creating any Kendo widgets? Do anybody has any idea what is wrong in here?

```
<html>
<head><title>KendoUI </title>
<link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="name">Text</div>
<input id="datepicker" />
<br/>

<ul id="menu">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu").kendoMenu();
    $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you see in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Wanna try adding a JSFiddle so we can see it?

Comment: got it working. Files were not referenced properly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Define the styles as:

```
<link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

`rel` is a required attribute and specifies the *relationship* between the current document and the linked resource.